# Remove all characters before nth occurrence

Tags: python, substring

Is there an equivalent to `CHARINDEX/SUBSTRING` from SQL in Python?

What I am trying to do is remove the characters before the 3rd `'` and after the 4th `'` meaning it will leave me with just the numeric value.

```
a = "[counter('check', Id('23345675'))]"
```

Expected String Output:

```
a = "23345675"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want everything between the 3rd and 4th `'` you can split the string on `'` and get the 3rd part:

```
a = "[counter('check', Id('23345675'))]"
a.split("'")[3]  # "23345675"
```

Note that you can also split a certain number of times, for example if you want everything after the 3rd `'`:

```
a.split("'", 3)[-1]  # this gives: "23345675'))]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for some regex parsing:

```
import re

test_string = "[counter('check', Id('23345675'))]"
pattern = re.compile(r"(?:.*?'){3}(.*?)'")
m = pattern.match(test_string )
print(m.group(1))
```

The pattern essentially says find anything that ends with ' 3 times, then capture the part until the next '

Answer (score 2):

Not very familiar with SQL, but are you looking for something like this?

```
>>> a.split("'")[3]
'23345675'
```